# Remove all buttons from customer edit page in adminpanel magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, admin-panel

I want remove all buttons from customer edit page in adminpanel in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

If You want definitely remove buttons for all users in Customer Edit Page You can do it by delete  nodes in section `<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">` in file:
`\app\code\Magento\Customer\view\base\ui_component\customer_form.xml`

Delete just buttons You need to delete.

Comment: I tried it is not working i placed the code into app/code/magento/customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml and i removed node "still it is not working" it reflecting changes from vendor/magento_customer/view\base\ui_component\customer_form.xml only

Comment: Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` after that

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove one of the buttons added into vendor/magento/module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml, declaring a new customer_form.xml file into a custom module with the following path:

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml

and the content will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="order" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

In this case I'm removing the "Create Order" button, but you can do the same for all the items declared into the core customer_form.xml file.